# How to Obtain Top Errors from MNIST?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I am experimenting with the MNIST dataset, and I am trying to obtain and print out the images of the top 5 errors my neural network has made. Top errors are defined as the largest distance between the probability of the predicted value and the actual value.
I am printing out the images with "plt.imshow", with plt from the MatPlotLib.pyplot function.

Here is my method for printing out the top errors:

1. print out the index of the maximum value of an errors_prob array that contains the differences in probability between the expected and actual values.
2. delete the value whose index I just printed out (using np.delete)
3. repeat this process 5 times

Below is the part of the code I am having a problem with:

```python
#wrong
actual_classes = #list numbers the network should predict, actual/expected
#list of the index of the errors/incorrect predictions
errors = np.asarray(np.nonzero(network.predict_classes(test_images) != actual_classes)).T
#errors_sorted = the difference in probability between what network predicted and what it should have predicted (predicted-expected)
errors_prob = np.zeros(len(errors)).reshape(len(errors),1)
for i in range(0,len(errors)):
  errors_prob[i] = np.abs((predicted_prob[int(errors[i])][int(actual_classes[int(errors[i])])]-predicted_prob[int(errors[i])][int(predicted_classes[int(errors[i])])]))

#print out the top 5 errors
for i in range(0,5):
    plt.imshow(train_images[np.argmax(errors_prob)])
    errors_prob = np.delete(errors_sorted,np.max(errors_prob))
```

Below is how I set up the network, in case you wish to consult this.

```python
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

#process the data

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')/255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)


#create the model
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='tanh', input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', 
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


#train and evaluate the images
network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)
test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
print('test_acc:', test_acc)
print (network.summary())


#todo: 
predicted_classes = network.predict_classes(test_images)
predicted_prob = network.predict_proba(test_images)

#wrong
actual_classes = np.zeros_like(predicted_classes)
for i in range(0,len(test_labels)):
    for j in range(0,len(test_labels[i])):
        if(test_labels[i][j] == 1):
            actual_classes[i] = j
errors = np.asarray(np.nonzero(network.predict_classes(test_images) != actual_classes)).T
errors_sorted = np.zeros(len(errors)).reshape(len(errors),1)
for i in range(0,len(errors)):
  errors_sorted[i] = np.abs((predicted_prob[int(errors[i])][int(actual_classes[int(errors[i])])]-predicted_prob[int(errors[i])][int(predicted_classes[int(errors[i])])]))

for i in range(0,5):
    print(np.argmax(errors_sorted))
    errors_sorted = np.delete(errors_sorted,np.max(errors_sorted))
```

Comment: First of all, you didn't say _what_ the problem _is_. Are you getting an error? Are you getting only 4 values instead of 5? Are you getting 5 values but they aren't the top?
Secondly, a much much more simple mechanism would be to `sort` and then just take the top 5 as `[:5]`...

Comment: I think there are two mistakes in the loop. 1) a typo: You are using `errors_sorted` in one place where it should be `errors_prob`. 2) a conceptual error: because you are modifying `errors_prob` (by deleting some elements) it ceases to be aligned with `train_images` and you can no longer simply use `argmax` on `errors_prob` as an index into `train_images`.

Comment: @ShlomiF I was thinking I should do that, however, I would then lose the index of the image I am trying to print out. Sorry to be unclear, the problem was that my code was not printing out the images of the top 5 errors.

Comment: @H.Khan you can use `argsort` to get indices